# Flutter - Using Firestore with Laravel passport

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, laravel-passport

I created my flutter application with Laravel passport api for auth, and now i want to use Firebase's Firestore for push notifications and messaging, how am i supposed to move forward?
All Firestore tutorials i find are joined with firebase auth.

Is there any way i can implement to actually let firestore work in parallel with laravel?

Comment: I'm keen to find out if you have managed to implement anything to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your auth concern separated just like you have. What you're looking for is just FCM and there are some great packages for that I believe. I personally have built and implemented multiple back-end scenarios exactly like this.

An example of such would be as follows:

Back-End:

- Laravel 7++
- passport for auth (sometimes custom grants created for use case, e.g. SaaS)
- fcm provider (custom self developed)
- uses api routes exclusively, nothing goes through the web guard here (API First)

Front-End/App:

- Angular 9+ / React / Vue2+

  - standard oauth using password grant (you should look into PKCE)
- Flutter APP

  - standard oauth (custom built) with provider state management

Communication / Scenario:

Imagine flutter app and front-end like portal app in Angular, imagine your goal is to keep the data on both in sync? There are many ways to accomplish this, but also imagine that you really do not need any sort of stream, so what do you do?

You follow observer pattern that'll get you exactly where you wanna be. In this case I would simply choose Firebase Cloudmessaging and have my apps and pwa / spa subscribe to a channel.

## Logic: (Passive aggressive reactive approach)

1. App 1 triggers an update of data
2. Back-end receives request, processes and triggers an update notification to channel
3. Other apps listening on that same channel (FCM) will go and call the API to get updated data.

So as simple as that you have created a very reactive system, and people won't know the difference that it isn't live streaming information from a -> b